# mp3play sometimes work, sometimes doesn't

Tags: python, mp3

I am using mp3play and google tts api to play the robot voice out:
The code is simple and but it was sometimes good, sometimes bad:

```
def robot_voice(text):
    text=text.split()
    text='+'.join(text)
    url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+text
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0') 
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()

    f = open("data.mp3", "wb")
    f.write(opener.open(request).read())
    f.close()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    import mp3play
    mp3=mp3play.load('data.mp3')
    mp3.play()
    time.sleep(mp3.seconds())
    mp3.stop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    robot_voice("hello world")
```

like when i put the file in one file folder, it simply plays out the voice"hello world", but when I copy and paste it in another one, it gives error messege:

> Error 277 for "open" data.mp3 "alias mp3_0.395468745176": problem occurred while initializing MCI. 
>   Error 263 for "set mp3_0.395468745176 time format milliseconds": The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI. 
>   Error 263 for "status mp3_0.395468745176 length": The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\Sample\synthesis\robot_voice.py", line 28, in 
>       robot_voice("hello world")   File "C:\Python27\Sample\synthesis\robot_voice.py", line 19, in robot_voice
>       mp3=mp3play.load('data.mp3')   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mp3play__init__.py", line 10, in load
>       return AudioClip(filename)   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mp3play__init__.py", line 17, in **init**
>       self._clip = _PlatformSpecificAudioClip(filename)   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mp3play\windows.py", line 43, in **init**
>       self._length_ms = int(buf) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   '\xd6\xb8\xb6\xa8\xb5\xc4\xc9\xe8\xb1\xb8\xce\xb4\xb4\xf2\xbf\xaa\xa3\xac\xbb\xf2\xb2\xbb\xb1\xbb
>   MCI \xcb\xf9\xca\xb6\xb1\xf0\xa1\xa3'